# One Click on Nav Menu Trigger several actions

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have 3 menus in a nav and each menu has a submenu.  I need to do 2 acts when clicking on a menu, or plus/minus sign.

**First Act**: When I click:

1. show `this` submenu
2. change `this` plus sign to minus sign
3. Close other submenus
4. Change other submenus signs from minus to plus

**Second Act**: When I click on an element which has an open submenu, again

1. submenu will be closed.
2. minus sign change to plus sign

My JQuery is working as expected on the **First Act**, but somehow it doesn't work on the **Second Act**

Please give me a hand.  Thanks

```js
$(function(showHidesubMenu) {
$('.parent-list').click(function() {
  $(this)
    .toggleClass('open').next().toggleClass('icon-minus icon-plus')
    .add($('.parent-list.open').not(this).removeClass('open').next().toggleClass('icon-minus icon-plus'))
    .parent().next('.child-layer').toggleClass('show')
})
  })

$(function() {
$('.plus-minus').click(function() {
$(this)
.prev().toggleClass('open')
.next().toggleClass('icon-minus icon-plus')
.add($('.parent-list.open').not(this).removeClass('open'))
.parent().next('.child-layer').toggleClass("show");
})
})
```

```css
li {
  display: flex
}
.icon-plus:before {
  content: "\2795";
}
.icon-minus:before {
  content: "\2212";
}
.parent-list {
  padding-right: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.collapse {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="non-active">
    <a class="non-active parent-list" href="#level1">level 1</a>
    <div class="plus-minus icon-plus">&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
  <ul class="child-layer collapse">
     <li>Sub Child 1</li>
     <li>Sub Child 1</li>
     <li>Sub Child 1</li>
 </ul>
   <li class="non-active">
    <a class="non-active parent-list" href="#level2">level 2</a>
    <div class="plus-minus icon-plus">&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
  <ul class="child-layer collapse">
     <li>Sub Child 2</li>
     <li>Sub Child 2</li>
     <li>Sub Child 2</li>
 </ul>
   <li class="non-active">
    <a class="non-active parent-list" href="#level3">level 3</a>
    <div class="plus-minus icon-plus">&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
  <ul class="child-layer collapse">
     <li>Sub Child 3</li>
     <li>Sub Child 3</li>
     <li>Sub Child 3</li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(showHidesubMenu) {
  $('.parent-list').click(function() {
    $(this)
      .toggleClass('opening') // add class mark this opening
      .next()
      .toggleClass('icon-minus icon-plus')
      .add(
        $('.parent-list.opening')
          .not(this)
          .removeClass('opening')
          .next()
          .toggleClass('icon-minus icon-plus')
      )
      // to parent toogle ul
      .parent()
      .next('.child-layer')
      .toggleClass('show')
  })
})
```

```css
li {
  display: flex
}
.icon-plus:before {
  content: "\2795";
}
.icon-minus:before {
  content: "\2212";
}
.parent-list {
  padding-right: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.collapse {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="non-active">
    <a class="non-active parent-list" href="#level1">level 1</a>
    <div class="plus-minus icon-plus">&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
  <ul class="child-layer collapse">
     <li>Sub Child 1</li>
     <li>Sub Child 1</li>
     <li>Sub Child 1</li>
 </ul>
   <li class="non-active">
    <a class="non-active parent-list" href="#level2">level 2</a>
    <div class="plus-minus icon-plus">&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
  <ul class="child-layer collapse">
     <li>Sub Child 2</li>
     <li>Sub Child 2</li>
     <li>Sub Child 2</li>
 </ul>
   <li class="non-active">
    <a class="non-active parent-list" href="#level3">level 3</a>
    <div class="plus-minus icon-plus">&nbsp;</div>
  </li>
  <ul class="child-layer collapse">
     <li>Sub Child 3</li>
     <li>Sub Child 3</li>
     <li>Sub Child 3</li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Tachibana Shin, Thank you!  Your script works great.  Please let me know how '.add($('.parent-list.opening').not(this).removeClass('opening').next().toggleClass('icon-minus icon-plus'))' works out?

Comment: basically `.add(<array>)` adds the items in `<array>` to the existing object in the code I add the items to execute the following commands along with the previous objects of function `$()` above

Comment: you can shorten my code further by moving `.add()` up 2 lines and removing `.next().toggleClass(...)` from `.add()`

Comment: Thank you for explain the `add()` function here.  I wonder what script makes a current opening submenu closed after you click on another menu?

Comment: it looks for `.opening` and closes them

Comment: I try to do the same actions when I click on plus and minus signs, but the current opening submenu doesn't close after I click on another menu.  I just updated my script in my snippet.  Please take a look what is missing

Comment: because `this` reference is wrong please change `$('.parent-list.open').not(this)` to `$('.parent-list.open').next().not(this ).prev()` and don't update the question it makes it difficult for me to constantly edit the answer

Comment: I wonder why  in `.add(...)` we just only remove `open` class, (but don't remove class `show` in `.child-layer`, a current opening submenu will be closed after we click on another menu.  Can you please explain?

Comment: since the class `.show` already exists in their `.child-layer` we only need `toggleClass` (command below)